# Merge 2 XML files with XSLT and change attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge 2 XML files and modifying the attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351207/merge-2-xml-files-and-modifying-the-attribute-values)

I have two xml files. I want to merge them and make some arithmetic with a few attributes. Please provide some ideas. I am using a standard xslt http://informatik.hu-berlin.de/merge to merge the files.

File 1:
coverage branch-rate="0.5125" branch-total="50" line-rate="0.00593031875463"

File 2:
coverage branch-rate="0.5" branch-total="40" line-rate="1.0"

Expected Result File
coverage branch-rate="(0.5125*50 + 05*40)/(50+40)" branch-total="50" line-rate="0.00593031875463"

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.  People on SO are willing to help, but not if you are not willing to invest some work yourself. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].

Comment: You have essentially asked this question three times on here and have not acknowledged the help you've received. Definitely not cool.

Comment: Thanks for approving my answer, @Messiah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed that File 1 and File 2 each consist of a single element, `<coverage>`, with the attributes you have provided. I have also assumed that there will always be two files and no more. I wasn't sure how all the calculations worked for your result so I guessed. I have used more variables than necessary to make the calculations more concise and readable.

You should be more explicit when asking for help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name = "b1" select="document('file1.xml')/coverage"/>
        <xsl:variable name = "b2" select="document('file2.xml')/coverage"/>
        <xsl:variable name = "b1_br" select="$b1/@branch-rate"/>
        <xsl:variable name = "b1_bt" select="$b1/@branch-total"/>
        <xsl:variable name = "b1_lr" select="$b1/@line-rate"/>
        <xsl:variable name = "b2_br" select="$b2/@branch-rate"/>
        <xsl:variable name = "b2_bt" select="$b2/@branch-total"/>
        <coverage>
            <xsl:attribute name="branch-rate">
                <xsl:value-of select="(($b1_br * $b1_bt) + ($b2_br * $b2_bt)) div ($b1_bt + $b2_bt)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$b1/@branch-total"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$b1/@line-rate"/>
       </coverage>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```